# Laravel sort order for both relationship and current table

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I have a review table and review_photos. I would like to get all reviews from a specific product order by their updated_at column and priortise reviews with photos to display first within the specific date. The solution below will only return reviews with photos only, the ones without photo it won't display.

Review model

```
public function photos()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\Models\Booking\ReviewPhoto');
}
```

ReviewPhoto model

```
public function review()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Models\Booking\Review');
}
```

ReviewRepository

```
public function getProductReviews($product_id, $paginate = false)
{
    $query = $this->review->where('product_id', $product_id)->whereHas('photos')->orderByDesc('updated_at');

    if ($paginate !== false) {
        return $query->paginate($paginate);
    }

    return $query->get();
}
```

Comment: you can use something like this. `$query = $this->review->where('product_id', $product_id)->orderByDesc('updated_at')->orderBy('photo_id');` this will short table first on the basis of updated_at then photo_id or you can change it to vice versa.

Answer (score 0):

to get a connection without conditions, you can use **with**

$query = $this->review->where('product_id', $product_id)->with('photos')->orderByDesc('updated_at');